# MassTransit Service Bus Configuration and Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, dependency-injection, masstransit

For MassTransit, when setting up a new service bus the endpoint/type must be declared; however, I am trying to remove that dependency so that when I do tests against the consumer I can utilize the loopback endpoint but once in production, it would use the actual msmq endpoint.

Below is an example setup of a new service bus:

```cs
public class ConsumerService
{
    IServiceBus _bus;

    public void Start()
    {
        // Initalize Service Bus
        _bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
        {
            //x.UseMsmq();
            x.ReceiveFrom("loopback://localhost/MyQueue");
            x.SetConcurrentConsumerLimit(1);
        });
        _bus.SubscribeConsumer(() => new MyConsumer());
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _bus.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Constructor Injection**:

```
public class ConsumerService
{
    private readonly IBusInitializer initializer;

    public ConsumerService(IBusInitializer initializer)
    {
        this.initializer = initializer;
    }

    IServiceBus _bus;

    public void Start()
    {
        // Initalize Service Bus
        _bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(x =>
        {
            this.initializer.initialize(x);
            x.SetConcurrentConsumerLimit(1);
        });
        _bus.SubscribeConsumer(() => new MyConsumer());
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _bus.Dispose();
    }
}
```

where `IInitializer` is a properly defined interface, and implementations could be:

```
public class LoopbackInitializer : IBusInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(WhateverXIs x)
    {
        x.ReceiveFrom("loopback://localhost/MyQueue");
    }
}

public class MsmqInitializer : IBusInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(WhateverXIs x)
    {
        x.UseMsmq();
    }
}
```

Inject the desired implementation in your test or [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot).

Answer (score 2):

What I did to enable testing using `MassTransit` was to encapsulate the dependency on the service bus in an interface, and then inject this dependency into my classes.

The interface for the `bus`

```
public interface IPublishBus {
    void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class;
}
```

Then the implementation used in production

```
public class MassTransitBridge : IPublishBus {
    private IServiceBus _ServiceBus;
    private static readonly string __SubscriptionServiceQueue;
    private static readonly string __MassTransitBridgeQueue;

    static MassTransitBridge() {
        __SubscriptionServiceQueue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mtSubscriptionService"];
        __MassTransitBridgeQueue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mtBridgeQueue"];
    }

    public MassTransitBridge() {
        _ServiceBus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc => {
            sbc.UseMsmq(mq => {
                mq.UseSubscriptionService(__SubscriptionServiceQueue);
                mq.Configurator.UseControlBus();
                mq.Configurator.SetCreateTransactionalQueues(true);
            });
            sbc.DisablePerformanceCounters();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom(__MassTransitBridgeQueue);
            sbc.UseControlBus();
            sbc.UseJsonSerializer();
        });
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class {
        _ServiceBus.Publish<T>(message);
    }
}
```

While testing I use the following `Mock` object that's injected into my services

```
public class PublishBusMock : IPublishBus {
    public static List<Object> Messages { get; private set; }

    public PublishBusMock() {
        Messages = new List<object>();
    }

    public void Publish<T>(T message) where T : class {
        Messages.Add(message);      
    }

    public static void ClearMessages() {
        Messages = new List<object>();
    }
}
```

The `Mock` object allows me to test whether the right messages where raised by the `object` being tested.

Also injecting it this way allows me to swap out `MassTransit` for something else that implements `IPublishBus` if the need arises